# Encryption in transit not working in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, ssl

I am using MongoDB 4.0.6 with 3 node replica set. I am upgrading my cluster to use SSL, below are steps which i am following :

1) generated CA.pem, server.pem and client.pem file and updated in my mongo config,

```
  dbPath: /xvdf/data/lib/mongodb
  journal:
    enabled: true
  engine: wiredTiger

systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  logRotate: reopen
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: (IP address)
  ssl:
    mode: allowSSL
    PEMKeyFile: /etc/server.pem
    CAFile: /etc/ssl/ca.pem


processManagement:
  pidFilePath: /var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid

replication:
  replSetName: test

security:
  keyFile: /etc/mongodb-test-keyfile
```

2) After updating my config i restarted mongo, It is successfully started with SSL option.

3) Next i ran command db.adminCommand( { setParameter: 1, sslMode: "preferSSL" } ) so it will allow both SSL and nonSSL connection from client.

4) After that when i enabled SSL from client side, I updated my API config with "SSL : true" and with certificates, I am getting bellow error on mongo log file :

**"Error receiving request from client: SSLHandshakeFailed: SSL peer certificate validation failed: certificate signature failure"**

Please help me on this ASAP.

Thanks.. :)

Comment: Are you using Enterprise version of Mongodb.

Comment: No. I am using community version.